# ArgumentCaptor for a generic list always returns an empty list

Tags: mockito

When trying to capture an ArrayList parameter with an ArgumentCaptor the resulting object is always an empty list.

I am using the @Captor annotation to create my ArgumentCaptor but it still results in an empty list being returned.

```
 @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    public class Test{

        @Mock
        private Service service;

        @Captor
        private ArgumentCaptor<ArrayList<SomeType>> secondCaptor;

        @Before
        public void init(){
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        }

        @Test 
        public void shouldDoStuffWithListValues(){

        ArgumentCaptor<SomeType> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(SomeType.class);

        //...

        verify(service).doStuff(captor.capture(), secondCaptor.capture()));

        SomeType type = captor.getValue();
        List<SomeType> someTypeList = secondCaptor.getValue();

        //this assert is fine
        Assert.assertTrue(type != null);

        //whereas; this assert always fails, despite the call containing a value
        Assert.assertTrue(someTypeList.size()>0);

        }
    }
```

Comment: The most plausible explanation is that the service is indeed being called with an empty list. Or that the list is being cleared after the call is made. We can only make guesses since you didn't post the code. Post a **complete** minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: Thanks - you were spot on, despite the object being populated correctly on entering the mocked method, it was then subsequently being cleared ready for a possible next iteration.